# CSS rule to apply for element that was the only one in its parent

Tags: html, css

I have this marked up

```css
.parent {
  padding:5px;
}

.parent  .child:only-child {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="elem1 child">
 Child
</div>
<div class="elem2 child">
 Child
</div>
<div class="elem3 child">
 Child
</div>

</div>
<div class="parent">
<div class="elem1">
 Child 
</div>
<div class="elem2">
 Child
</div>
<div class="elem3 child">
 I need to change it here
</div>
</div>
```

As you can see,
I am not sure how to detect the "elem3 child" in second parent class.
In this class, elem3 actually the only element has class child.

Are there any Css rule to select it in this case ?
Thank for you help.

Comment: this would help... https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: i tried nth-child already and it not work :(

Comment: Are you allowed to change the html part by adding class? Or be able to use javascript, jquery as well?

Comment: what exactly are you looking for?.... from the question it seems that you want to get any/all elements where the class is 'child', but only for the 2nd parent, i.e.:  .parent:nth-child(2) .child { color:red }

Comment: Hi AlqbalRaj. As you can see. First parent class have more than one .child elements. The second has only one .child class. I want to detect this only one child by using css

Comment: There is no selector in CSS allowing something  to be styled if it's the only child, and only in that case.

Answer (score -1):

Please see below if it is work for you:

```css
.parent {
  padding:5px;
}

.parent [class="elem2"] + [class="elem3 child"] {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="elem1 child">
     Child
    </div>
    <div class="elem2 child">
     Child
    </div>
    <div class="elem3 child">
     Child
    </div>
    
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
    <div class="elem1">
     Child 
    </div>
    <div class="elem2">
     Child
    </div>
    <div class="elem3 child">
     I need to change it here
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This may help. But if you want it to be a generalized selection than javascript selector is the only option.

```css
.parent {
  padding: 5px;
}

.parent:nth-of-type(2) > div.child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="elem1 child">
    Child
  </div>
  <div class="elem2 child">
    Child
  </div>
  <div class="elem3 child">
    Child
  </div>

</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="elem1">
    Child
  </div>
  <div class="elem2">
    Child
  </div>
  <div class="elem3 child">
    I need to change it here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @quan-truong you might have not liked the solution above and downvoted but there is no selector for the condition you want in CSS.

Comment: as a side note : quan-truong doesn't have enough reputation to downvote